# having 2 physics bodies changes the behavior of the node

Tags: sprite-kit, collision, skphysicsbody, bounce

I have a rectangle shaped node, I want this node to behave like a pool ball when it hit the wall, meaning it bounce of the wall in a reverse angle, just like the pool ball, here is what I did:
1- Added `physicsBody` `rectangleOfSize`, the behavior is not as it supposed to, the node hit the wall then moves along it instead of bouncing in the correct angle.

2- Added `physicsBody` `circleOfRadius`, the behavior is perfect, but the node is not circle shaped, it's rectangle.

3- Finally found the most logical solution, I added two bodies `circleOfRadius`, one at the top of the node and one at the bottom,this way I should get the bouncing behavior I want with the top one, and still give the node a practical physics body for collisions with the bottom one, but the behavior is like the rectangle shaped physics body rather than the circle shaped one.

```
 let circle = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: size.width / 2, center: CGPoint(x: 1, y: size.height / 2))
 let circle2 = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: size.width / 2, center: CGPoint(x: 1, y: -size.height / 3))
 physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [circle, circle2])
```

Seems like the bottom circle body is affecting the behavior, I tried playing with its properties(`allowsRotation`, `mass`, etc) but it changed nothing.

Any idea how to make a rectangle shaped node behave physically like a circle shaped one?

Comment: With restitution = 1.0 is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section for ["Working with Collision and Contacts"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/) in the Apple Docs for a SKPhysicsBody. Basically you have do define a collisionBitMask for your circle node to only collide with your walls and your rectangle node to only collide with whatever you want it to collide with.